Micropartitions and External Tables
I am going through the snowflake documentation. I am yet to find an answer for the following question(s)

is there any relation between external stages and micropartiions as in data from external stages will be loaded in micropartions ?
Will data be copied to micropartitions from external stages when a table loaded ?

Please share your thoughts

Hi - the title of your question mentions external tables but then your question actually talks about external stages - which one do you mean, table or stage? In any case, micro- partitions are relevant only to standard Snowflake tables and not to external tables or stages
